# cop file from remote conatiner to localmachine?

Tags: kubernetes

how i acces my namespace:  kubens namespace
how i access my pod: acces my container: kubectl exec -it hello-6b588fc8c-jz89q --container test  -- bash

i wante to cp a file from the filebeat container. but not work i try

Comment: What happens when you try any of these variations?  Can you provide a relevant fragment of application code, or other details required for a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

From the `kubectl cp --help` output, an example is provided for your use case (copying from a remote pod to your local filesystem):

```sh
# Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

In your case, I believe the command would be

```sh
kubectl cp <namespace-of-pod>/dsp-onboarding-6b588fc8c-jz89q:/app/data/logs/dsp-onboarding.json.log . -c filebeat
```

Note the `-c` option is necessary in your case, since you want to `cp` the file off of a specific container in the pod.

Comment: when i run your command : kubectl cp dsp-onboarding/dsp-onboarding-6b588fc8c-jz89q:/app/data/logs/dsp-onboarding.json.log . -c filebeat  .


this com out :
`
tar: Removing leading /' from member names
error: open .: is a directory  `

Comment: Perhaps try `kubectl cp dsp-onboarding/dsp-onboarding-6b588fc8c-jz89q:/app/data/logs/dsp-onboarding.json.log dsp-onboarding.json.log -c filebeat` instead. If that works, please let me know, and I can update my answer.

Comment: i solve it like this :  remove /     before /app